# Apache2::Const qw() equivalent for Apache::Constants qw(:common :response)

Tags: perl, apache, apache2, porting

I'm still banging my head against the wall with attempting to port a legacy perl application from Apache 1.3.x (and who really knows what version of perl) to RHEL6...which is Apache 2.2.x / perl 5.10.x

At any rate, if there is anyone that knows the equivalent for

```
use Apache::Constants qw(:common :response);
```

... needs to be refactored to use Apache2 ...

```
use Apache2::Const qw(:common :response);  <--This is _not_ correct.
```

it looks like there is :common, but :response throws the error: "unknown apache2_const:: group `response'"

Also, if anyone can "teach a man to fish" here, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't import anything and you use `use strict;`, you'll almost surely get compilation errors if you use a constant you didn't import. So could just use

```
use Apache2::Const qw( );
```

then add to the import list what you actually need, as determined by looking at the compile-time error messages.

Comment: Thanks.  If nothing else, let the compiler tell you want it needs.

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs, importing using the TAG `:common` will bring the following:

```
Apache2::Const::AUTH_REQUIRED
Apache2::Const::DECLINED
Apache2::Const::DONE
Apache2::Const::FORBIDDEN
Apache2::Const::NOT_FOUND
Apache2::Const::OK
Apache2::Const::REDIRECT
Apache2::Const::SERVER_ERROR
```

do you know what tags exactly are you willing to use when importing `:response`? if so, try looking for them [here](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/mod_perl-2.0.7/docs/api/Apache2/Const.pod)

Comment: This helps.  Thank you for getting me in the right direction.

Comment: So, I'm digging through the docs some, and I've noticed that there are no equivalents for some of the 'common' response codes from mod_pero 1.x (http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/api/Apache/Constants.html#Synopsis) to mod_perl 2.x

Comment: do you know exactly what constants are you willing to import? I also suggest looking at: http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/porting/compat.html#C_Apache__Constants_

Comment: I'll have to dig through the source code to see.  I _love_ legacy stuff.